# SCJP - number format

Tags: java, certificate, number-formatting, scjp

Given:

```
public class LineUp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 12.345;
        // insert code here
    }
}
```

Which code fragment, inserted at line 4, produces the output `| 12.345|`?

> ```
> A. System.out.printf("|%7d| \n", d);
> B. System.out.printf("|%7f| \n", d);
> C. System.out.printf("|%3.7d| \n", d);
> D. System.out.printf("|%3.7f| \n", d);
> E. System.out.printf("|%7.3d| \n", d);
> F. System.out.printf("|%7.3f| \n", d);
> Answer: F
> ```

What is the interpretation of the printf statements , why is the |%7d| is giving `illegalFormatConversionException ?`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because d is a double and it can't be formatted as a decimal integer.You can't use the "d" format descriptor in case of floating-point variables, without an explicit cast in order to signal the fact that you are aware of the possible loss of precision.

Comment: *"...it can't be formatted as a decimal."* It can't be formatted as a decimal ***integer***. It *can* be formatted as a decimal. "Decimal" just means "base 10" and doesn't speak to integer vs. floating point.

Answer (score 3):

Because %d formats an integer.

From the doc:

```
'd'     integral    The result is formatted as a decimal integer
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class's `format()` method takes a format string of the form:

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

`System.out.printnf()` is a convenience method that uses the same arguments.

So `%7d` indicates a `[width]` of 7 and a `[conversion]` of `d` which is for integral types. In this example, the value being passed is a `double` which cannot be formatted as an integral type.